# git: Push all local branches that track a specific remote

Tags: git, git-push

I'm looking for an equivalent of `git push --all` that is restricted to a specified `remote` and pushes only local branches that track *that* remote.

`git push --all myremote` does not do the trick, for example:

```
% git push nh2github --all --dry-run
To github.com:nh2/myrepo.git
 + f4165c1e160...6882a13b8c1 branch1-tracking-nh2github -> branch1-tracking-nh2github
 + e5998342793...010aa57c786 branch2-tracking-nh2github -> branch2-tracking-nh2github
 * [new branch]              branch3-tracking-otherremote -> branch3-tracking-otherremote
```

This is not good because it pushes *all* local branches, including those that track a different `remote` than the `nh2github` I've specified.

How can this be done?

Comment: Why not `git push remote`?

Comment: @GregBurghardt Because `git push remote` does something completely different than what I asked for: It pushed the _current_ branch to `remote`, not all branches tracking that remote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list branches and their upstream branches I recommend [`git for-each-ref`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref):

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)'
```

Filter the list by chosen remote with `awk` (print branch names):

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)' |
    awk '$2 ~ /^refs\/remotes\/<MYREMOTE>\// {print $1}'
```

And now go pushing:

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads --format='%(refname:short) %(upstream)' |
    awk '$2 ~ /^refs\/remotes\/<MYREMOTE>\// {print $1}' |
    xargs git push <MYREMOTE>
```

(In the above, replace `<MYREMOTE>` by your remote's name.)

Comment: Thanks, this works great. I'm accepting this answer because it takes as input variable only the desired `<MYREMOTE>` and does everything else by itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can grep your way out of `git config -l` to target the branches linked to a specific remote :

```
# each branch linked to a remote will have two lines :
#   branch.[branch name].remote = trackedremote
#   branch.[branch name].merge = refs/heads/remote/name
# you can keep the local branches that track a ref from targetremote :
git config -l | grep '^branch\.' | grep '\.remote = targetremote$'

# use another command to extract the actual branch name :
# awk would work
... | awk -F . '{ print $2 }'
```

You can then feed the list of branches to git push :

```
branches=$(command above)
git push targetremote $branches
```